# TF2.0: How to create a tensor with numpy attribute

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to create a tensor with numpy attribute and tried this:

```
tensor1 = tf.reshape(tf.constant([100, 100, 100], dtype=tf.int64), (-1, 1))

print(tensor1)

 #tensor1
 tf.Tensor(
[[100]
 [100]
 [100]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=int64)
```

But the output does not show the tensor ID or the numpy attribute where the values will be an array. How do I create a tensor of that format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still has the numpy method, just call it:

```
tensor1 = tf.reshape(tf.constant([100, 100, 100], dtype=tf.int64), (-1, 1))

print(tensor1)
print(tensor1.numpy())
```

Also, look at the difference between

```
print(str(tensor1))
```

and

```
print(repr(tensor1))
```